# Problema - Linq SQL Server: consulta indesejada na base de dados ao atribuir valor em um campo derivado do banco de dados

Tags: .net, linq, query

Tudo bem pessoal

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho o método abaixo que só tem o trabalho de atualizar um campo na base de dados,  a classe t_sap_log_jobs que é passada como parâmetro foi criada automaticamente quando o LINQ foi configurado.

```
public void UpdateReprocessar(List<t_sap_log_jobs> lstJob, int intStatus)
{
    try
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext(entity.Connection);
        var transacao = new Transacao(db, () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in lstJob)
            {
                // Consulta job
                var query = (from t in entity.t_sap_log_jobs
                                     where t.cd_log_job == item.cd_log_job
                                     select t).FirstOrDefault();

                // quando atribuio o intStatus no campo query.cd_status (que é uma FK na base de dados) uma consulta // é disparada no banco de dados.
                query.cd_status = intStatus;

                // Salva alteracao no banco de dados
                entity.SaveChanges();
            }
        });

        transacao.Executar();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Após verificar lentidão no banco de dados, consegui detectar através do *profiler* que toda vez que atribuo valor no campo `cd_status` a consulta abaixo é executada no banco de dados. Lembrando que o campo cd_status é uma FK de outra tabela.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [Extent1].[cd_log_job] AS [cd_log_job], 
                   [Extent1].[cd_tipo_operacao] AS [cd_tipo_operacao], 
                   [Extent1].[cd_chave_atividade] AS [cd_chave_atividade], 
                   [Extent1].[dt_processamento] AS [dt_processamento], 
                   [Extent1].[dc_erro] AS [dc_erro], 
                   [Extent1].[qt_tentativa] AS [qt_tentativa], 
                   [Extent1].[dt_ultimo_processamento] AS [dt_ultimo_processamento],                                                               [Extent1].[cd_status] AS [cd_status] 
                   FROM [dbo].[t_sap_log_jobs] AS [Extent1] 
                   WHERE [Extent1].[cd_status] = @EntityKeyValue1',
    N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',
    @EntityKeyValue1=3 
    go
```

Deve haver alguma configuração para que o LINQ não se comporte dessa forma, alguma idéia?

Answer (score 1):

Há várias coisas esquisitas no seu código. Esta é uma delas:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(entity.Connection);
```

Não está claro o que é `entity` no seu código. Acredito eu que seja outro contexto. De qualquer forma, `db` é usado apenas para o escopo transacional, o que é contraproducente.

A alteração não é na atribuição. É neste ponto aqui:

```
// Salva alteracao no banco de dados
entity.SaveChanges();
```

Se `lstJob` é muito grande (mais de 1000 registros, por exemplo), vai ficar lento mesmo. [Nesta outra resposta que dei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21932/o-que-pode-causar-a-queda-de-desempenho-do-ef-nesse-cen%C3%A1rio/21991#21991) há algumas estratégias para melhorar o desempenho.

Outra coisa que pode ser feita é chamar o `entity.SaveChanges()` apenas uma vez, ao final de todas as suas alterações:

```
        foreach (var item in lstJob)
        {
            // Consulta job
            var query = (from t in entity.t_sap_log_jobs
                                 where t.cd_log_job == item.cd_log_job
                                 select t).FirstOrDefault();

            // quando atribuio o intStatus no campo query.cd_status (que é uma FK na base de dados) uma consulta // é disparada no banco de dados.
            query.cd_status = intStatus;
        }

        // Salva alteracao no banco de dados
        entity.SaveChanges();
```

Na prática, o desempenho é sensivelmente menor porque o contexto é otimizado para trabalhar com atualização de vários registros de uma vez.