# Trabalhando com Entity Framework, Multithreading e SQL Server em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, multithreading

Estou usando o `Entity Framework` e `Multithreading` em um projeto `C#` e estou passando por problemas de conexão com o `SQL Server`.

Bom, queria melhorar a velocidade de umas buscas de dados para um grid pois são selects muito demorados. Primeiramente usei multithreading nas consultas e vi que na verdade não fazia diferença eu acionar as consultas em diferentes threads, porque no banco ele acaba enfileirando as consultas como se eu estivesse em um laço normal. Para conseguir resolver isso, começei a instanciar vários escopos, repositórios e connectionstring's novos a cada trhead que eu crio, para que ele faça os selects como se fossem pessoas diferentes acessando o banco e assim rode todas as consultas em paralelo. Funcionou, de certa maneira, porem quando crio muitas threads em algumas consultas ele da problemas como `The underlying provider failed on open` e `Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto`, porem, nem sempre é na mesma consulta, é meio que aleatório. Alguem já passou pora tal problema ou possui uma solução para o mesmo? Também estou aberto a sugestões caso haja um jeito melhor de fazer o que estou fazendo. Abaixo está meu codigo:

```
public void BuscarDadosGridFamilia(string filialSelecionadaCodigo, string familiaSelecionada, string legendaSelecionada)
{
    _listaClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto.Clear();

    DateTime dataInicialPeriodoVendas = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
    DateTime dataFinalPeriodoVendas = DateTime.Now;
    _totalVendas30Dias = 0;
    _totalEstoqueAtual = 0;
    _totalEstoquePrevisto = 0;
    _totalCapacidadeMin = 0;
    _totalCapacidadeMax = 0;
    _totalGiroObj = 0;
    decimal _totalGiroAtual = 0;
    decimal _totalGiroPrevisto = 0;
    decimal _totalGiroCapacidadeMax = 0;
    decimal _totalGiroObjetivo = 0;
    decimal _totalGiroIdeal = 0;
    int _quantidadeTasks = 0;
    int _totalLinhasGridFamilia = 0;
    string[] filialSplit = filialSelecionadaCodigo.Split('-');
    Filial filialSelecionada = _filialAplicacao.RepositorioFilial.ObterPorCodigo(_usuarioAtual.LocalEstoqueAtual.Filial.Empresa, filialSplit[0].Trim());

    var _familiaProduto = _familiaProdutoAplicacao.RepositorioFamiliaProduto.Todos()
                            .Where(d => d.FlagPercentualCapacidadeGondola == 1)
                            .Where(d => (d.Codigo.StartsWith(familiaSelecionada + ".") || d.Codigo == familiaSelecionada) && familiaSelecionada != "");

    if (legendaSelecionada != "Todos")
        _familiaProduto = _familiaProduto.Where(d => d.FamiliaMarcadaCapacidadeGondola.LegendaLinha.Legenda == legendaSelecionada.Split('-')[0].Trim());

    Task[] tasks = new Task[_familiaProduto.Count()];

    foreach (var familia in _familiaProduto)
    {
        ConexaoBanco.ConexaoMultiThread = "familia-" + familia.Codigo;
        string connectionString = ConexaoBanco.GetConexao();
        ConexaoBanco.ConexaoMultiThread = "familia-" + familia.Codigo;
        IRepositorioEscopo escopo = Havan.Infra.IoC.Container.Obter<IRepositorioEscopo>();

        ParametrosTask parametrosTask = new ParametrosTask();
        parametrosTask.familia = familia;
        parametrosTask.filialSelecionada = filialSelecionada;
        parametrosTask.legendaSelecionada = legendaSelecionada;
        parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo = escopo;

        Task _task = new Task(() => BuscarDadosGridFamiliaTask(parametrosTask), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
        _task.Start();
        tasks[_quantidadeTasks] = _task;

        _totalLinhasGridFamilia++;
        _quantidadeTasks++;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    try { _totalGiroAtual = Arredondar((_totalEstoqueAtual / _totalVendas30Dias) * 30); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_totalGiroAtual = 0); };
    try { _totalGiroPrevisto = Arredondar((_totalEstoquePrevisto / _totalVendas30Dias) * 30); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_totalGiroPrevisto = 0); };
    try { _totalGiroCapacidadeMax = Arredondar((_totalCapacidadeMax / _totalVendas30Dias) * 30); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_totalGiroCapacidadeMax = 0); };
    try { _totalGiroIdeal = Arredondar((_totalVendas30Dias / 30) * _totalGiroObjetivo); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_totalGiroIdeal = 0); };
    try { _totalGiroObjetivo = Arredondar(_totalGiroObj / _familiaProduto.Count()); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_totalGiroObjetivo = 0); };

    ClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal = new ClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto();

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.Filial = "TOTAL:";
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.Vendas30Dias = _totalVendas30Dias;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.EstoqueAtual = _totalEstoqueAtual;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.EstoquePrevisto = _totalEstoquePrevisto;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.CapacidadeMin = _totalCapacidadeMin;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.CapacidadeMax = _totalCapacidadeMax;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.GiroAtual = _totalGiroAtual;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.GiroPrevisto = _totalGiroPrevisto;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.GiroCapacidadeMax = _totalGiroCapacidadeMax;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.GiroObjetivo = _totalGiroObjetivo;
    _classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal.GiroIdeal = _totalGiroIdeal;

    if (_listaClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto.Count > 0)
        _listaClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto.Add(_classeGenericaFamiliaProdutoTotal);

    gridFamilia.DataSource = _listaClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto;
}
```

E agora o método que é chamado pelas `Tasks` que contem consultas ao banco por `LINQ`

```
public void BuscarDadosGridFamiliaTask(ParametrosTask _parametrosTask)
{
    decimal _estoqueSeparadoFamiliaLoja = 0;
    decimal _estoqueTransitoFamiliaLoja = 0;
    decimal _estoqueEntrarFamiliaLoja = 0;
    decimal _estoqueLogicoFamiliaLoja = 0;
    decimal _estoquePrevistoFamiliaLoja = 0;
    DateTime dataInicialPeriodoVendas = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
    DateTime dataFinalPeriodoVendas = DateTime.Now;

    _familiaProdutoAplicacao = new FamiliaProdutoAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _filialAplicacao = new FilialAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _dadosFamiliaFilialAplicacao = new DadosFamiliaFilialAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _giroObjetivoFamiliaProdutoAplicacao = new GiroObjetivoFamiliaProdutoAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _saldoEstoqueProdutoAplicacao = new SaldoEstoqueProdutoAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _resumoVendasAplicacao = new ResumoVendasAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _legendaLinhaAplicacao = new LegendaLinhaAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _wrkGenerico01Aplicacao = new WrkGenerico01Aplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _parametroClasseABCFamiliaAplicacao = new ParametroClasseABCFamiliaAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);
    _usuarioAtualAplicacao = new UsuarioAplicacao(_parametrosTask.repositorioEscopo);

    Int64 _idPrimeiroNivelFamilia = _familiaProdutoAplicacao.RepositorioFamiliaProduto.ObterPorCodigo(_parametrosTask.familia.Codigo.Split('.')[0]).FirstOrDefault().Id;

    ParametroClasseABCFamilia _parametroClasseABCFamilia = _parametroClasseABCFamiliaAplicacao.ParametroClasseABCFamiliaPorFamiliaClasse(_parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.Id, _idPrimeiroNivelFamilia).FirstOrDefault();

    ClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto = new ClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto();

    _saldoEstoqueProdutoAplicacao.ObterSaldoEstoqueProdutosFamilia(_usuarioAtual.TipoEstoque.Id, _parametrosTask.filialSelecionada, _parametrosTask.familia.Codigo, true, out _estoqueLogicoFamiliaLoja, false, out _estoqueSeparadoFamiliaLoja, false, out _estoqueTransitoFamiliaLoja, false, out _estoqueEntrarFamiliaLoja, true, out _estoquePrevistoFamiliaLoja);

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Filial = _parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.Codigo + " - " + _parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.Apelido;

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.LinhaProduto = _parametrosTask.familia.FamiliaMarcadaCapacidadeGondola.LegendaLinha.Descricao; }
    catch (Exception) { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.LinhaProduto = ""; };

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Familia = _parametrosTask.familia.Codigo;

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.DescricaoFamilia = _parametrosTask.familia.Nome;

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias = Arredondar((decimal)_resumoVendasAplicacao.RepositorioResumoVendas.ObterQuantidadeVendaPorFamiliaFilial(_parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.Id, _parametrosTask.familia.Id, dataInicialPeriodoVendas, dataFinalPeriodoVendas)); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias = 0); };

    _totalVendas30Dias += Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias);

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoqueAtual = Arredondar(_estoqueLogicoFamiliaLoja);

    _totalEstoqueAtual += Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoqueAtual);

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto = Arredondar(_estoquePrevistoFamiliaLoja);

    _totalEstoquePrevisto += Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto);

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMin = Arredondar(_dadosFamiliaFilialAplicacao.RepositorioDadosFamiliaFilial.ObterLimiteMaximoFamiliaEstoque(_familiaProdutoAplicacao.RepositorioFamiliaProduto, _usuarioAtual.LocalEstoqueAtual.Filial.Empresa.Id, _usuarioAtual.TipoEstoque.Id, _parametrosTask.familia.FamiliaMarcadaCapacidadeGondola.Codigo, _parametrosTask.familia.Codigo, _parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.Id).Select(d => d.Quantidade).FirstOrDefault());

    _totalCapacidadeMin += Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMin);

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMax = Arredondar(_familiaProdutoAplicacao.CalculoEstoqueMaximoFamilia(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMin, _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias, _parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.TempoReposicaoEmDias, _parametroClasseABCFamilia.FatorClasseFamilia, _parametroClasseABCFamilia.PercentualCabideFamilia)); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMax = 0); };

    _totalCapacidadeMax += Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMax);

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroAtual = Arredondar((_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoqueAtual / _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias) * 30); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroAtual = 0); };

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroPrevisto = Arredondar((_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto / _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias) * 30); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroPrevisto = 0); };

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroCapacidadeMax = Arredondar((_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMax / _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias) * 30); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroCapacidadeMax = 0); };

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroObjetivo = Arredondar(_giroObjetivoFamiliaProdutoAplicacao.BuscaGiroObjetivoFamiliaMaisProxima(_parametrosTask.familia.Codigo, _parametrosTask.filialSelecionada.Id));

    _totalGiroObj += Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroObjetivo);

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroIdeal = Arredondar((_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.Vendas30Dias / 30) * _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroObjetivo); }
    catch (Exception) { Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroIdeal = 0); };

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.NecessidadeGiro = (Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroIdeal - _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto) < 0 ? 0 : Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroIdeal - _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto));

    _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.NecessidadeCapacidade = (Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMax - _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto) < 0 ? 0 : Arredondar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.CapacidadeMax - _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.EstoquePrevisto));

    try { _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.SGiro = Formatar((_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroPrevisto / _classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.GiroObjetivo) * 100); }
    catch (Exception) { Formatar(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto.SGiro = 0); };

    _listaClasseGenericaFamiliaProduto.Add(_classeGenericaFamiliaProduto);
}
```

Comment: Você já conseguiu identificar quais consultas estão demoradas? Minha aposta: uma mudança em apenas uma ou duas linhas pode melhorar várias vezes o tempo de resposta desta parte do teu sistema. Eu começaria por analisar esta aqui:  `_familiaProdutoAplicacao.RepositorioFamiliaProduto.Todos().Where(...` - veja que você primeiro retorna mais registros do que precisa e depois faz uma seleção em memória. Apesar de o seu design não parecer ideal, na maioria das vezes o problema de performance é localizado. Identifique qual das consultas está tomando 80% do tempo e volte aqui pra gente dar uma olhada.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado pela dica! faz sentido! Irei implementar. Porem a minha duvida é outra.

Comment: Hmm sua dúvida é com as threads, certo? Acabei me concentrando no que me pareceu ser o verdadeiro problema e me esqueci das threads. Teu design abre bastante brecha para problemas ao trabalhar com threads. Já que você está aberto a sugestões, a minha sugestão é: não use threads. Elas não foram feitas para resolver problemas de performance, menos ainda problemas de performance em consultas a SGBDs (eles próprios abrem threads quando necessário). É melhor voltar ao código anterior sem as threads, identificar e resolver os problemas de performance.

Comment: Bom, com as dicas de vocês e bastante leitura acabei abandonando essa ideia de threads fazendo vários acessos paralelos ao BD e optei por mudar a estrutura um pouco e melhorar minhas consultas. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Isto aqui:

```
_familiaProdutoAplicacao.RepositorioFamiliaProduto.Todos()
```

É péssimo em todos os sentidos para a performance, visto que você faz um `TABLE SCAN` para cada consulta. [Aqui explico porque usar repositório com Entity Framework não vale a pena](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/unidade-de-trabalho-unit-of-work-com-reposit%C3%B3rio/33285#33285).

A segunda coisa que me chamou a atenção é quantas consultas você faz para sintetizar a informação. Não sei como está o seu código por baixo disso, mas é muito provável que a mesma informação seja trazida várias vezes. Quanto mais cheio o contexto (que no seu caso é compartilhado), mais lento ele fica. [Aqui nesta resposta ensino como otimizar o contexto para grandes porções de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21932/o-que-pode-causar-a-queda-de-desempenho-do-ef-nesse-cen%C3%A1rio/21991#21991), mas creio que o ganho será pequeno pela forma com que sua aplicação foi construída.

Sugiro repensar toda essa arquitetura. Posso ajudar se você der mais detalhes das suas consultas LINQ.

Comment: Valeu cigano! agradeço pela dica e a documentação. Irei implementar. Agora como eu disse ao @Caffé, A minha duvida é outra. Por mais que minhas consultas estejam demoradas e usar repositório não vale a pena.