# Erro de memória ao inserir milhões de registros usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou usando o Entity Framework para Fazer inserção e atualização de milhares de Registros.

De início ficou lento, mas após colocar o código abaixo melhorou a velocidade.

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;  
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Velocidade Resolvido.

Porém, eu não consigo chegar até o final pois, conforme vai inserindo, o modelo vai ficando grande e aumentando o consumo de memória até me dar exceção ao chegar em 1,5GB de uso.

Obs.: Já tentei usar o `AsNoTracking()`.

Também estou tentando recarregar o modelo de tempo em tempos, mas não abaixa o consumo. Somente aumenta.

Alguém passou por essa situação ou tem alguma ideia?

Parte do código:

```
foreach (var prd in produtoGradeAux)
{
    if (dbPdv.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
       dbPdv.Database.Connection.Open();

using (var transaction = dbPdv.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    dbPdv.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
    i++
    Produto prodAux = null;
    var pAux = dbPdv.produto_grade.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.produto_GradeIdGw == prd.produto_gradeID);

    if (prd.cd_grade.Trim().Length > 6)
        pAux = dbPdv.produto_grade.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.cd_grade.Trim() == prd.cd_grade.Trim());

    if (prd.cd_grade.Trim().Length > 6)
        prodAux = dbPdv.produto_grade.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Produto.cd_ref.Trim() == prd.cd_grade.Trim().Substring(0, 6)).Select(x => x.Produto).FirstOrDefault();

    int lnFamiliaId, lnGrupoId, lnUnidadeId, lnMarcaId, lnLinhaId;

    RetGrupos(prd, out lnFamiliaId, out lnGrupoId, out lnUnidadeId, out lnMarcaId, out lnLinhaId, dbPdv);

    if (pAux == null)
    {
        if (prodAux == null)
            prodAux = RetProduto(dbPdv, prd.Produto, lnFamiliaId, lnGrupoId, lnUnidadeId, lnMarcaId, lnLinhaId);
        pAux = RetProdutoGrade(dbPdv, prodAux, prd);
        SetProdutoEan(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
        SetProdutoCf(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
        SetProdutoEstoque(dbPdv, lojaAux, prd, pAux);
        SetProdutoPreco(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
    }
    else
    {
        AtuProdutoGrade(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
        AtuProduto(dbPdv, prd, pAux, lnFamiliaId, lnGrupoId, lnUnidadeId, lnMarcaId, lnLinhaId);
        AtuProdutoEan(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
        AtuProduto_Cf(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
        AtuProduto_Preco(dbPdv, prd, pAux);
        AtuProdutoEstoque(dbPdv, lojaAux, prd, pAux);
    }

    transaction.Commit();

    //Tentar Melhorar performance...
    if (i % 1000 == 0)
    {
        HabilitaDb(dbPdv);
        dbPdv.Dispose();
        dbPdv = GetDbPdv(pdvAux);
        DesabilitaDb(dbPdv);
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: Você fez o que deve fazer e não dá para ajudar muito mais sem saber como está seu código. Já pensou em fazer com SQL ao invés de EF? Ele não precisa ser usado para tudo. É possível que você esteja com vazamento de memória. Respondi sobre isto (caso específico) à pouco http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/84277/101

Comment: Opa.. Obrigado Pela Resposta.. Irei colocar Parte do Código na Pergunta

Comment: Cada entidade adicionada ao contexto continuará lá enquanto o contexto existir ou até que você limpe o contexto. O processamento sequencial de grande volume de entidades você deve fazer em lotes, por exemplo: a cada 100 entidades você persiste e as elimina do contexto.

Comment: Opa Obrigado @Caffé .. To Fazendo de 1000 em 1000... tentei 500 também mas não vi muita diferença

Comment: À parte do seu código (que eu não gastei muito tempo tentando entender) vou dar uma sugestão de algoritmo: cria o contexto, depois de X entidades lidas, processadas e persistidas, envia as alterações para o banco, destrói o contexto e cria outro contexto para as próximas X entidades. Se quiser reutilizar o mesmo contexto você terá que desatachar cada entidade para que elas possam ser eliminadas da memória - não vejo necessidade; destruir contexto e criar outro novo está ok.

Comment: Boa Ideia @Caffé.. Estou usando o  `dbPdv.Dispose();` e depois Recriando ele na atraves do `GetDbPdv()` na Variável DbPdv. Isso não Funciona? Realmente Desatachar não seria o mais Viável.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O **Entity Framework** não foi feito para inserir 1 milhão de registros... 
Ele tem um limite em Memoria interna...(index dele) AsNoTracking() não irá resolver... Já efetuei os testes mais complexos possíveis.

Para esse tipo de inserção parte para um **ORM** menor... com menos gerenciamento e detalhes... no caso um **MicroORM**, como por exemplo **Dapper, PetaPoco**, etc..

Caso não seja viavel, ultilize o **Bulk Insert**, que é uma implementação ADO.net para o entity framework.
[EntityFramework.BulkInsert](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Na minha opinião, Recomendo utilizar nesses casos o **ADO.net** para esses processos que necessitam de performance em uma grande quantidade de transição de dados. Pegando dados de conexão do contexto do **entity framework** ou config. Pois você não fica limitado apenas no INSERT(bulkinsert), podendo efetuar outras operações.
Uma opção empresarial, em um sistema grande, é partir para o **NHibernate**. Por experiencia pessoal e testes efetuados.

---

Caso for o **Entity Framework Core**, veja [esse link](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

Comment: Obrigado @daniloloko.. Irei Avaliar essas outras alternativas..

Comment: Apos Trocar para o ADO.Net Resolveu.

Answer (score 5):

[Nesta resposta, explico várias alternativas que você pode usar para melhorar o desempenho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21932/o-que-pode-causar-a-queda-de-desempenho-do-ef-nesse-cen%C3%A1rio/21991#21991), mas não creio que, mesmo usadas em conjunto, irão resolver seu problema completamente.

Há algumas coisas que me chamaram a atenção em seu código. Por exemplo:

```
if (dbPdv.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   dbPdv.Database.Connection.Open();
```

Isto não é necessário. O próprio Entity Framework é responsável por controlar o ciclo de vida da conexão.

Isto:

```
using (var transaction = dbPdv.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    dbPdv.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
    ...
```

Também não está alinhado com as boas práticas do Entity Framework (suporte a transações distribuídas). O correto seria abrir um [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.118).aspx) com opção de [`ReadUncommited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.transactions.transactionoptions.isolationlevel(v=vs.118).aspx) no `IsolationLevel`:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            new TransactionOptions()
            {
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
            }))
{
    ...
```

Para o seu caso, a resposta do @Daniloloko é o caminho a seguir. [O pacote NuGet do EntityFramework.BulkInsert está aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/).

Comment: Obrigado pela Dicas.. Irei Alterar , e conforme você falou darei uma Olhada no BulkInsert. Obs: Ele Somente Faz Insert ?Update não?

Comment: Sim, apenas insert.

Comment: Será Que somente No insert Resolverá minha Situação? Visto que Também Faço Updates.. Não inchará a Memoria?

Comment: Como você faz insert e update, o caminho é realizar o `Dispose` do contexto a cada 1000 ou 2000 registros.

Comment: Puxa, isso eu ja faço conforme pode vir acima..  Mesmo Assim Obrigado pela Suas respostas..